# isEqual function always returning true with every

Tags: javascript, function

This function checks if two Objects have the same values:

```
_.isEqual = (a, b) => {
  const aKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)
  const bKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b)
  if (aKeys.length !== bKeys.length) {
    return false
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < aKeys.length; i++) {
    var propName = aKeys[i]
    if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}
```

I replaced the for loop with `every`:

```
_.isEqual = (a, b) => {
  const aKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)
  const bKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b)
  if (aKeys.length !== bKeys.length) return
  return aKeys.every((key, index) => {
    return key === bKeys[index]
  })
}
```

However, the function returns `true` even if a and b aren't equal.

What did I do wrong?

**Input:**

```
const obj1 = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  z: 0
}

const obj2 = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  z: 0
}
```

Comment: You used `return` twice in a row in the revised code.

Comment: @Sablefoste But that code only returns `true` if the `lengths` are different.

Comment: There is a syntax error, literally `return return aKeys.every((...`  The way I read it, the function shouldn't return anything at all as rewritten and should throw a `Unexpected token return` error.  What does the console.log say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var first = "hello"
var second = "meow"

console.log("recognized")

isEqual(first,second);

function isEqual(a, b) {
    console.log("running")
  const aKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)
  const bKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b)
  if (aKeys.length !== bKeys.length) {
    console.log("false")
    return false
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < aKeys.length; i++) {
    var propName = aKeys[i]
    if (a[propName] !== b[propName]) {
        console.log("false")
      return false
    }
  }
  console.log("return true")
  return true
}
```

prints out false if I change `second` to `hello`, it will print out true. I would say it has to do with your input data. have you tried using a smaller set of input data just to make sure its all good?

**Update:** Or is your problem only with the second interation? if that's the case you have two `return` statements

```
var first = ["shoop", "doop", "woop", "loop", "koop"]
var second = ["hamp","damp", "samp", "wamp"]

console.log("recognized")

var returned = isEqual(first,second);

console.log(returned)

function  isEqual(a, b) {
  const aKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)
  const bKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b)
  if (aKeys.length !== bKeys.length) {
    return aKeys.every((key, index) => {
      key === bKeys[index]
    })
  }
}
```

This is probably what you are looking for. if `akey` and `bkey` lengths are not equal the `every` methods will do its thing and return `false` in this case as `key` and `bkey` are not equal and `false` is returned. `if (aKeys.length !== bKeys.length)` is not true, `undefined` will be returned as its the nature of js

In response to the comment "how can it be done with returning either true or false" you can return `true` in the event the if statment is never run i.e `bkeys.length` is equal to `akeys.length`

```
var first = ["shoop", "doop", "woop", "loop"]
var second = ["hamp","damp", "samp", "wamp"]

console.log("recognized")

var returned = isEqual(first,second);

console.log(returned)

function  isEqual(a, b) {
  const aKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)
  const bKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b)
  if (aKeys.length !== bKeys.length) {
    return aKeys.every((key, index) => {
      key === bKeys[index]
    })
  }
  else{
   return true
  }
}
```

Comment: How should I solve the problem with the two return statements?

Comment: Same problem, the function always return true. (I changed !== to === but I have the same problem)

Comment: If the code above I have given isn't working with the input data you are using, I would suspect and issue with the input data

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to cover:

#### 1. Arrow functions take two forms:

1. `(x) => x` returns x.
2. `(x) => { ... }` executes the statements inside `{}` like a normal function.

Either add `return` in your `{}` or modify it to be the first form.

```
return aKeys.every((key, index) => {
  return key === bKeys[index]
})
```

or

```
return aKeys.every((key, index) => key === bKeys[index])
```

---

#### 2. Property list is not ordered

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames({a:1, b:2, c:3})` is not guaranteed to return in the order `['a', 'b', 'c']`. Depending on the JS implementation. V8 tries hard to keep the order but not all JS implementations will. It could return `['c', 'a', 'b']`.

To fix this, you could sort the lists.

```
const aKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a).sort()
const bKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b).sort()
```

---

#### 3. Compare values as well as keys.

As written, your loop only compares the keys. `{a:1, b:2}` and `{a:5, b:5}` will return `true` because you're only checking that `a` and `b` exist, but are not comparing their values.

You could do this:

```
return aKeys.every((key, index) => {
  if (key !== bKeys[index]) return false
  if (a[key] !== b[key]) return false
})
```

but it only tests shallow objects. If an object contains another object, it will always return false since `{} !== {}`. You'll need to add a check for "if it's an object, then recursively call _isEqual".

---

#### 4. An alternative to ordering/sorting keys:

Instead of ordering the keys, you could do this:

```
return aKeys.every((key, index) => {
  return b.hasOwnProperty(key)
})
```

but it may be less performant. Try a benchmark to see.

Comment: Thanks but the function keeps returning `true` regardless of the value of obj1 or obj2. That doesn't happen with the for loop version.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
_.isEqual = (a, b) => {
  const aKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)
  const bKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b)
  if (aKeys.length !== bKeys.length) return
  return aKeys.every((key, index) => a[key] === b[bKeys[index]])
}
```

I was compating the `keys` and not the `values`! That's why the function was always returning `true`.

Comment: were you using lodash's isequal?

Comment: @BenniMcBeno No, I was trying to reproduce lodash's isEqual to get better at JavaScript.

Comment: `a[key] === b[key]` should work equally well except `every` accepts `element, index, list` as its parameters, so given your equation it should be `a[index] === b[index]` fwiw, this is not a deep equals which "Performs a deep comparison between two values to determine if they are equivalent."

Comment: Hey @alex I've updated my answer with a more thorough analysis. I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In your revised code, you need to return `false` or the result.  You should add an else statement:

```
_.isEqual = (a, b) => {
  const aKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a)
  const bKeys = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b)
  if (aKeys.length !== bKeys.length){
     return false;
  } else { // <-- this is new here //
     return aKeys.every((key, index) => {
       key === bKeys[index]
     })
  }
```

Comment: I thought `every` would `return` false if the condition was false. So i didn't need to do it myself.